# Como calcular campos em um formulário AcrobatDC usando javascript?

Tags: javascript, formulário, pdf

Tenho um formulário PDF e quero que um dos itens funcione da seguinte forma: Após os campos A, B, C, e D serem preenchidos, num outro ponto do formulário, A, B, C e D aparecem como opções de uma listbox. De acordo com a opção escolhida, o campo original (A, B, C ou D) é somado ao Campo Y, e o resultado aparece no campo X. Como atrelar a escolha do campo a ser somado à escolha na listbox? Detalhe: não entendo nada de javascript, só o bastante pra copiar o código de um lugar e colar no outro, substituindo os nomes dos campos.

Estou usando o Adobe Acrobat DC, que me permite criar formulários com uma interface intuitiva, mas que usa scripts para cálculos. Ele me permite pegar dois campos e calcular dentro dessa interface, mas não sei lidar com a listbox.

Acho que sei como explicar melhor o que preciso: quero saber como trabalhar a listbox para importar o valor do outro campo para que eu possa somar o objeto listbox (se é que isso é possível) a outro objeto. Exemplo: Minha listbox tem as opções A, B e C. Vamos supor que A é igual a 5, B é igual a 4 e C é igual a 7. Esses valores vão ser inseridos pelo usuário final. O que eu quero é uma forma de fazer com que o valor do objeto selecionado, A, B ou C, passe a ser temporariamente o valor da minha listbox pra que eu possa somar listbox + Y.

Comment: Javascript dentro do PDF ou em uma página HTML que chama o PDF? Está um pouco dificil de entender o que já fez, na verdade esta bastante dificil de entender quase tudo.

Comment: @guilherme-nascimento, seria dentro do PDF. Os campos já existem, o que eu não sei fazer é atrelar os campos A, B, C e D aos itens de mesmo nome da listbox. Mais claro?

Comment: Eu conheço pouco o AcrobatDC, só mexi uma vez para criar um formulario PDF, todavia seria mais facil se você explicasse +ou- como esta o formulário

Comment: Posso postar links aqui?

Comment: Depende do link, mas não custa tentar

Comment: https://files.acrobat.com/a/preview/18198919-9670-46be-b29b-7fa9a311c8ac

Comment: Lais como a pergunta esta fechada eu não vou conseguir por um script um pouco mais completo, mas mesmo que conseguisse acho que não iria lhe ajudar, então vou tentar lhe dar um caminho, pra pegar o listbox desejado use `var f = this.getField("ListBox1");` (troque ListBox1 pelo nome do listbox desejado) e depois com 
`var a = f.currentValueIndices;` você irá pegar apenas os itens selecionados, ae basta somar eles usando um `for`

Comment: Vou tentar reabrir a pergunta

Comment: Vou tentar aqui, obrigada!

Comment: Laís acho que consegui fazer um exemplo completo, pela manhã eu falo com um moderador pra reabrir a pergunta ae posto o código e umas explicações, até breve.

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda, Guilherme!
O que você já me passou, o programa não está aceitando. Ele simplesmente some.